# Android weightSum does not work

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-layout-weight

i have coded a ListViewAdapter to show rows in an activity with special Items. But my problem it isn't working as it should. My goal is, that the elements in a row have a fixed size and therefore i used weightSum. They should have a percentage.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100.0">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtID"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8.0"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtVis1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="36.0"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtVis2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="36.0"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editVis1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10.0"
        android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal|numberPassword|phone"
        android:text="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editVis2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10.0"
        android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal|numberPassword|phone"
        android:text="" />



</LinearLayout>
```

[And here is, how it looks like. Its obvious wrong. It should be alle the same size and in the middle should be the black line on every row at the same position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3Q50.jpg)

The strange think is that it worked in a very early build and now it does not work anymore. What can i do?

If you need other code just tell me ;-) Thanks.

Comment: It could be that issue is caused by `View` object because `View` also occupies some space which than extends your `100.0` and as I noticed you didn't count `View` in your `weightSum`. Anyway you don't even need `weightSum` you can remove that and directly provide `weights` in `Views` for example if you put in each of your `View weight=1` than each `View` inside `LinearLayout` will take same percentage of space. By increment of weight you will also give more space to particular `View`.

Comment: I highly recommend you to start using ConstraintLayout, especially for such functionalities.

Comment: Hey, thank you. I removed the View and it still doesn't worked... :(

Comment: @AlfgerReimer try on that way I described you.

Comment: @Yupi i have tried it. I removed weightSum and also tried to set each weight to 1. Still doesnt working and looks the same like before except that the View is now much bigger.. But still totally random and unequally.

Comment: @AlfgerReimer ah okay seems obvious now. Your `TextViews` have height as `wrap_content` and they will extend in `height` as much space as needed to fill all text.

Comment: Still not working. Set TextViews to match_parent. Here is how it looks now: http://prntscr.com/jndych  just as strange as before.

Comment: Try removing the `weight_sum` to see if it works. We may need to see the code you define the `ListView` and the adapter too because the layout seems fine

Comment: @AlfgerReimer plz share ur design exactly  what you want?

Comment: Why are you using the numbers like this? "100.0", "36.0"... And not like this? "100", "36"